# Why is std::less better than "<" for pointers?

Tags: c++, std, comparison-operators, unspecified-behavior

C++ primer, 5th, 14.8.2, Using a Library Function Object with the Algorithms:

```
vector<string *> nameTable;  // vector of pointers
// error: the pointers in nameTable are unrelated, so < is undefined
sort(nameTable.begin(), nameTable.end(),
     [](string *a, string *b) { return a < b; });
// ok: library guarantees that less on pointer types is well defined
sort(nameTable.begin(), nameTable.end(), less<string*>());
```

Then I checked the [`std::less` implementation in libc++](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/a09f09c618e9ec9ba8455ffa7f9765b240f0d16d/libcxx/include/__functional/operations.h#L392-L419) (code block modified for readability):

```cpp
template <class _Tp>
struct less {
    constexpr bool operator()(const _Tp& __x, const _Tp& __y) const
        {return __x < __y;}
};
```

I have found out that `std::less` also uses `<` to do the work, so why is `<` undefined for pointers and `std::less` isn't? Why would I use `std::less`?

Comment: Pointer-types are the important part here; you're looking at the primary definition of `less`, but I'd bet it also has a specialization for pointers that is far more relevant to your question. Importantly: "[*A specialization of `std::less` for any pointer type yields a strict total order, even if the built-in `operator<` does not.*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less)"

Comment: On your system the `<` operator might work the same as `std::less`, but it is not required to.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because `<` isn't always `operator<()`. Only classes have operator functions, so your suggestion would not work for the built-in types.

Furthermore, `<` on pointers doesn't necessarily implement a strict-weak ordering, whereas `std::less` (via specialisation — what you posted isn't "all" of `std::less`!) [is required to](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less):

> A specialization of std::less for any pointer type yields a strict total order, even if the built-in operator< does not.

In short: **`std::less` works for anything that supports a less-than comparison.**

Answer (score 2):

#### Why do we need `std::less`?

Comparison between pointers is only well-defined if both are part of the same array. Otherwise, the result is unspecified (see [[expr.rel]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.rel)).
Note that this isn't the same as undefined behavior.

This is problematic when sorting an array of pointers, keeping a `std::set<void*>`, etc. because the algorithms and data structures require a [strict weak ordering].
If some pointers are unordered, this is only a partial ordering.

`std::less` guarantees a strict total order, which is even stronger than a [strict weak order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings):

> For templates `less`, `greater`, `less_equal`, and `greater_equal`, the specializations for any pointer type yield a result consistent with the [implementation-defined strict total order over pointers](https://eel.is/c++draft/defns.order.ptr).
>
> [*Note*: If `a < b` is well-defined for pointers `a` and `b` of type `P`, then `(a < b) == less<P>()(a, b)`, `(a > b) == greater<P>()(a, b)`, and so forth.
> — *end note*]

- [[comparisons.general]](https://eel.is/c++draft/comparisons.general)

On architectures with [memory segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation), this could make `std::less` more expensive because both the base pointer and the offset within a segment would need to be compared.
It could be more efficient if `<` only provided a partial ordering, and the developer opted into `std::less` if they really need a total ordering.

#### Why is `std::less` simply delegated to `<` in libc++?

The quoted paragraph also hints at the reason why libc++ implements `std::less` using `<`: because `<` happens to be well-defined for Clang anyway, so its standard library doesn't have to do anything special.

However, this isn't guaranteed by the standard, and not every compiler gives such strong guarantees to the `<` operator. GCC doesn't provide a total order for `<`, and its standard library [implements `std::less`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/cf2ae3fff4ee9bf884b122ee6cd83bffd791a16f/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_function.h#L446-L459) using:

```cpp
// for two pointers x, y
return (std::uintptr_t)x < (std::uintptr_t)y;
```

The total order is achieved by comparing the memory addresses that the pointers represent, rather than the pointers directly.

#### Implementations of `std::less` compared

| Library | Header | Implementation for pointers `p`, `q` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GCC libstdc++ | **[bits/stl_function.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/cf2ae3fff4ee9bf884b122ee6cd83bffd791a16f/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_function.h#L446-L459)** | `(std::uintptr_t)p < (std::uintptr_t)q` (`<` is a partial order) |
| Clang libc++ | **[__functional/operations.h](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/a09f09c618e9ec9ba8455ffa7f9765b240f0d16d/libcxx/include/__functional/operations.h#L392-L419)** | `p < q` (`<` is a total order) |
| MSVC STL | **[type_traits](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/d8ed02d2ec7ba8216848a33dec2b5fb385febf4e/stl/inc/type_traits#L2434-L2456)** | `p < q` (`<` is a total order) |

Comment: I presume that implementation is only used by GCC for some architectures.  For example it might be trouble for real-mode x86 segmented pointers, i.e. DS:DX

Comment: @BenVoigt following the link to the libstdc++ code, I don't see any architectural switches. I don't think C++ is very friendly towards segmented architectures anyway, since `==` has to work for pointers and isn't allowed to spuriously succeed for completely different objects. The concept of near/far pointers doesn't exist in C++ (although it used to as an extension to ancient compilers), and I imagine that on segmented architectures, you would need to use a fat pointer to implement C++. Perhaps that's why GCC and Clang can get away with such simple implementations.

Comment: Well, segmented architectures (or other "based pointers" like into memory-mapped files) are the reason that `operator<` is only *required* to compare pointers into the same complete object (no, not restricted to arrays).  Because that guarantees to the compiler that the segment portion (or base of the pointer) are common between both operands.  But `std::less` has to work even when the segment / base portion differs.

Comment: @BenVoigt `==` comparison (see https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq#3) only allows unspecified behavior in the case of one-past-the-end pointers and object pointers. Given such a strict requirement (no spurious success for unrelated objects), I'm unsure how easily you could implement C++ pointers with segmented memory anyway.

Comment: I think you're right that the original intent was to give implementations more freedom with `<`, but this freedom doesn't look to be utilized in any standard library, and it's unclear whether you could utilize it given strict requirements for pointers in other places.

Comment: Gcc has some optimizations that assume that when p<q is executed, p and q must point into the same object.